# Kubuntu doesn't shutdown or restart via the start menu

Tags: kubuntu, shutdown, restart

I'm unable to shutdown on restart my pc unless I go to the lock screen and do it from there or type it via the konsole (`sudo shutdown -h now`).

When I click shutdown from the application menu, it blurs my screen and stays like that. What's weird is I can open up my start menu and open any application after this and If I close or minimize them, it'll go back to this blurry screen.

I have an onboard intel graphics and have made sure the drivers are upto date.

Comment: *I have an onboard intel graphics and have made sure the drivers are upto date*... Drivers are always up-to-date for Intel Graphics. What exactly did you do to "make sure"?

Comment: Made sure I haven't forgotten to update my kernel? since this is a fresh install? not sure how that's relevant here.

Comment: It could be relevant depending on what you actually did. If you have tried to manually install drivers that alone could be the cause. But you didn't so it isn't.

Comment: Nope, haven't installed any video drivers manually, noticed the issue happening right off the bat, so naturally I searched and most of the threads had people asking if the drivers were upto date, hence why I explicitly mentioned that I checked it.